# Django CMS case insensitive page urls

Tags: django, django-cms

I had implemented django cms and it seems that all the page URLs are case insensitive. Which means,

```
http://mydomain/contact-us/
http://mydomain/Contact-US/
http://mydomain/conTAct-us/
http://mydomain/cONTact-us/
http://mydomain/CONTACT-us/
```

are all accessible for the 'contact-us' page. Can i avoid this and make the cms page urls as strictly case -sensitive ?

Answer (score 0):

In Djnago CMS,all the urls are case-insensitive.In urls.py of CMS,it is given as:

if settings.APPEND_SLASH:
    reg = url(r'^(?P[0-9A-Za-z-*.//]+)/$', details, name='pages-details-by-slug')
else:
    reg = url(r'^(?P[0-9A-Za-z-*.//]+)$', details, name='pages-details-by-slug')
So i think it's not possible.